# How to install external javascript libraries on Parse cloud code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, request, twitter-oauth, parse-cloud-code

I am using these javascript libraries in my Parse cloud code.

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');
var Twit = require('twit');
```

The code will not compile unless I have these installed on the parse server. I am still using the parse server hosted by parse. How can I install these libraries in the parse server. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

in **parse.com** service you cannot add your own libraries to cloud code. If you want to integrate with http api you can use **Parse.Cloud.httpRequest**

In parse-server its totally different because there you have the freedom to add any library that you want. In order to add a new library to parse server cloud code  you need to do the following:

1. In your parse-server project open the **pacakage.json** file
2. Add your dependency under **dependencies** - you can add any library which available in NPM repository (which is actually... everything :) )
3. In command line run **npm install** in order to install the new dependency into your parse server
4. Go to cloud code and **require** this library and use it..

That's it.